# Regarding benign tumors and what 'stops' them

Tags: cancer, apoptosis

Benign tumors can grow to dangerous size yet are they capable of metastisizing ; if not what stops this? Also with a benign tumor if you call its cells 'near' its edges its tumor 'cell wall' I was wondering if the cells in its Tumor Cell Wall still have apoptosis mechanisms in them that function?

Comment: If tumors metastasize, they are not benign.

Comment: Afaik they still have apoptosis, but they slowly develop a resistance to signals which can trigger it. That's why they need stronger signals to stop proliferating than normal cells .

Comment: How do benign tumors develop a resistance to signals that can trigger apoptosis? If a benign tumor has stopped growing would this mean it has some active apoptosis mechanisms?